# 11-proef validation, foreign as well as national

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

If possible i would like some help a code.

In the Netherlands we use a BSN-number as personal identification. Which is based on a so called 11-proef validation. However, the system is allowed to add foreign Identifications as well.

It should validate the next examples: 
BE12345678910 (belgian has 11 numbers but is not validated in same way) so should always return true. NL123456789 (has the correct format, and should be validated with the code. 123456789 (also correct format, so should be validated with same code)

Below the code:
The one that only validates the 123456789:

```
Public Function ValidateBSN(bsnNr As String, ByRef errResult As Integer, Optional MaxLength As Integer = 9) As Boolean

        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(bsnNr) Then
            Return True
        End If

        Dim Length = bsnNr.Length

        If bsnNr.StartsWith("NL") Or Length = 9 Then

            Dim BSN As String = bsnNr.Replace("NL", "")

            Length = BSN.Length

            If MaxLength = Length Then

                Try
                    Dim _BSN As Int64 = Convert.ToInt64(BSN)
                    Return True
                Catch ex As Exception
                    Return False
                End Try

            Else
                Return False
            End If

        Else
            errResult = -1
            Dim param(0) As ErrorParam
            param(0) = New ErrorParam("BSN onjuist", "Voer een geldige BSN in.</br> Huidige waarde :<B> " + bsnNr.ToString() + "</b>")
            RaiseError("BSN onjuist", param)
            Return True
        End If

    End Function
```

the 11 proef:

```
Public Function CheckBSN(bsnNr As String) As Boolean

        'In our case BSN may be empty...
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(bsnNr) Then
            Return True
        End If

        ' A BSN consists of 9 characters ...
        If cleanBsnNr.Length <> 9 Then
            Return False
        End If

        ' ... all being numeric and not resulting in a 0 when converted to a number ...
        Dim l As Long
        If Not Long.TryParse(cleanBsnNr, l) Then
            Return False
        ElseIf l = 0 Then
            Return False
        End If

        ' ... the number must be validatable to the so-called 11-proof ...
        Dim total As Long = 0
        For i As Integer = 1 To 9
            ' 11-proof voor BSN's: (9*A + 8*B + 7*C + 6*D + 5*E + 4*F + 3*G + 2*H + (-1*I)) % 11 == 0
            Dim number As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(cleanBsnNr(i - 1).ToString())
            Dim multiplier As Integer = 10 - i
            If i = 9 Then
                multiplier = -1 * multiplier
            End If

            total += number * multiplier
        Next

        ' ... not result in a 0 when dividing by 11 ...
        If total = 0 Then
            Return False
        End If

        ' ... and not have a modulo when dividing by 11.
        Return total Mod 11 = 0

    End Function
```

I added this code just above the "in our case BSN may be empty" in the 11-proef.

```
Dim cleanBsnNr As String = Mid(bsnNr, 3, 9)
```

It does validate the NL123456789, but if active, validating 123456789 doesn't work anymore.

The reason for entering countrycode is so we can quickly recognize which country the personal identity number is from.

Comment: Please specify the language and technologies you are using. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, thanks for that reminder (edit will come), language is VB.net (or at leas tas far as i know. Program is Visual Studio 2013, ehm, not sure what you mean with technologies,